# Duda al crear un SELECT * FROM personas desde java

Tags: java, sql, base-de-datos

```
public void mostrar_personas() throws SQLException{
        Connection co = null;
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;



        String consulta = "SELECT * "
                      +   "FROM personas";

        try {


            co = iniciarConnection();
          preparedStatement = (PreparedStatement) co.prepareStatement(consulta);



            System.out.println();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            System.out.println(e.getMessage());

        } finally {

            if (preparedStatement != null) {
                preparedStatement.close();
            }

            if (co != null) {
                co.close();
            }

        }

    }
```

Es la primera vez que estoy manejando *Base de Datos* desde **Java** y pues me surgen dudas que agradeceria enormemente una respuesta, de nuevo, muchas gracias de antemano a todos

Comment: muchas dudas sobre qué?, no está claro cuál es la pregunta

Comment: un metodo que te muestre cada registro que hay en la tabla

Comment: es muy confusa la pregunta, que duda tienes, ¿si está bien tu código?

Comment: Yo creo que en vez de hacer 4 preguntas para cada operacion del CRUD hubieras tardado menos mirando un manual de Java y las BBDD https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/tutoriales/tutorial-basico-jdbc/

Comment: gracias encontre ahi la respuesta, yaa dije, soy nuevo y estoy aprendiendo, gracias a todos nuevamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Veamos:

En este caso no necesitas obligatoriamente un prepared statement. ¿Por qué?, porque la consulta no recibe datos desde el exterior, como sería el caso de un `INSERT` un `UPDATE` o un `SELECT` con una criterio `WHERE`.

El código de más abajo es el [ejemplo oficial de Java, para este tipo de consultas](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html). En el enlace hay también explicaciones sobre cómo se leen los ResultSets y las filas, lo único es que está en inglés, pero bueno, tampoco es tan complicado de entender.

Verás que:

- en ella se usa un objeto [`Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html), que no es lo mismo que un [`Prepared Statement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html).

Digamos que el `Statement` sirve para pasar la consulta  la BD sin tener que prepararla, porque en este caso no hace falta.

- su usa un objeto `ResultSet` para almacenar los datos obtenidos y recorrerlos, usando por ejemplo: `rs.getString("COF_NAME")` esto equivale a obtener los datos de la columna de la tabla llamada `COF_NAME` la cual es, digamos del tipo `VARCHAR` o cualquier otro equivalente a cadena. La columna `SALES` es de tipo entero, por eso sus datos se obtienen con `rs.getInt("SALES");`

  ```
          public static void viewTable(Connection con, String dbName)
          throws SQLException {

              Statement stmt = null;
              String query =
                  "select COF_NAME, SUP_ID, PRICE, " +
                  "SALES, TOTAL " +
                  "from " + dbName + ".COFFEES";

              try {
                  stmt = con.createStatement();
                  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                  while (rs.next()) {
                      String coffeeName = rs.getString("COF_NAME");
                      int supplierID = rs.getInt("SUP_ID");
                      float price = rs.getFloat("PRICE");
                      int sales = rs.getInt("SALES");
                      int total = rs.getInt("TOTAL");
                      System.out.println(coffeeName + "\t" + supplierID +
                                         "\t" + price + "\t" + sales +
                                         "\t" + total);
                  }
              } catch (SQLException e ) {
                  JDBCTutorialUtilities.printSQLException(e);
              } finally {
                  if (stmt != null) { stmt.close(); }
              }
          }
  ```

Comment: Simplemente perfecto, muchas gracias :)